# SceneKit dynamic object falls through static floor

Tags: swift, collision-detection, game-physics, scenekit

I have a SceneKit game in swift and in it I have a car with a dynamic physics body that is set up like this:

```
let carScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/truck.scn")!
    let carNode = carScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Cube", recursively: true)!



   let carPhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic,shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: 5.343, height: 12.125, length: 4.373, chamferRadius: 0)))

    carPhysicsBody.mass = 3
    carPhysicsBody.friction = 2
    carPhysicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1
    carNode.physicsBody = carPhysicsBody
    carNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
    carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 50, z: 0), asImpulse: true)

    car = carNode
    floorScene.rootNode.addChildNode(car)
```

The floor's physics looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the car gets launched into the air. Then the gravity in the scene makes it fall, and instead of colliding with the floor, it goes right through it.

The gravity looks like this:

[image]

What should I change so it will collide with the floor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a sample macOS playground, available at [github.com/heckj/scenekit-physics-playground](https://github.com/heckj/scenekit-physics-playground) that shows a physics body interacting. I suspect the core of the problem in your local example is that the floor object doesn't actually have an SCNPhysicsBody associated with it. Until I explicitly set it on SCNFloor (as static), the text blob "fell through" as you originally described.

I recommend adding `sceneView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsShapes]` to see the relevant debugging shapes. I've made (and pushed) a few updates to the above repo. Using stock SCNFloor to establish geometry for the physics collection made a tiny target (which is why the slight horizontal impulse made it appear to "pass through"). This last update sets the floor geometry to a long, wide, thin box.

Comment: Thank you now that the floor is a box the car is not falling through the floor

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the floor to be of the type [kinematic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514776-kinematic), not [static](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514791-static). With the car being dynamic and the floor being static, the floor isn't interacting with other objects in any fashion, and you explicitly want a collision.

UPDATE: static vs. kinematic doesn't make a difference for the collision interaction, either work effectively the same way, but having a physics body, and verifying it's size or viewing the interaction with `.showPhysicsShapes` may answer the underlying question of why they're not interacting.

Comment: I changed it to kinematic and the car still falls through the floor. Also, in an example project i did, the floor is static and collides with dynamic objects.

Comment: I even changed it to dynamic to see if the car would hit the floor then, just to see if the problem was with the body type, and it still fell through, i think it has to do with something else but i don't know what.

Comment: Do you have your sample on github or something public? The answer was strictly based on the docs, I'll see if I can hunt something down in a functional example

Comment: no i do not, would it be possible to include it here

Comment: I've made a sample macOS playground, available at https://github.com/heckj/scenekit-physics-playground that shows a physics body interacting. I suspect the core of the problem in your local example is that the floor object doesn't actually have an SCNPhysicsBody associated with it. Until I explicitly set it on SCNFloor (as static), the text blob "fell through" as you originally described.

Comment: I created the floor physics body in the SCNScene editor. Is there anything i have to do like in the code to assign it to the floor other than what i have shown above

Comment: I tried creating the floor physics body in code the way you did and the car still fell through the floor

Comment: I'm getting similar results with both Kinematic and Static, but depending on your contactBitMask and CollisionBitMask you can cause the physics to ignore each other. I'm also not sure why, but when I add a little horizontal impulse to my sample, the text collides and then as it's "falling over", it falls through the floor - I'm not clear why that's happening. I haven't used the editor in Xcode to manipulate scenes, so I don't have any additional suggestions for debugging or understanding why they're failing to interact.

Comment: I fixed the physics bodies i had the collision bit masks wrong. But now the same thing that happened to you happened to me. It hit the floor and bounced and turned and when it turned then it passed through the floor.

Comment: Set an explicit (and large) physics geometry for the SCNFloor object to give something explicit to interact with in a larger form. I noticed the default geometry for SCNFloor was tiny when I enabled `.showPhysicsShapes` on the `debugOptions`. Adding an explicit (and much larger) geometry for the floor area resolved the collision miss.

Answer (score 0):

One of posible solutions for u is to set collisionMargin property for your car from 0.0 to probably 0.01, I had the same problem for ball and plane.